# bcrypt.hashpw with flask error TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Tags: python, flask-wtforms, bcrypt

I am having in issue with utilizing bcrypt with flask form; if I use flask_bcrypt I have no issues. I get the error `TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing` when using `form.password.data.encode('utf-8')`. If I assign the value to `encrypted_password` and print it I get `b'password'` like you would expect, but when encrypting the value `bcrypt.hashpw(encrypted_password, os.getenv('SALT')` it will throw the error. Any suggestions?

The code can be found at https://github.com/TheDrunkenSkunk/encryption_test.git

**EDIT:** I found the issue, but do not know how to resolve it. When I call `os.getevn('SALT')` it will throw the error, however if I pass the SALT directly or call `bcrypt.gensalt()` it will work fine.

**EDIT 2** I have updated the repository with working code.

Comment: Why is your salt an environment variable? You should be using `bcrypt.gensalt()` anyway.

Comment: @Ry- I read it in a tutorial I found somewhere that it is good to do this for security purposes and so your salt can be cross instance. I mainly did it for verifying login, but now I found that I can do that by encrypting the login password with the stored password and verify it that way. Thank you for your input I would have never moved forward without it.

Comment: Glad you got it working! Whatever tutorial that is is dangerously wrong. Reusing salt means different users with the same password will clearly have the same password hash, which is a security issue.